# How to automate registering the OSSEC agent ip address on manager server?

Tags: bash, unix, devops, ossec

I want to automate the process of registering the OSSEC agent IP on the OSSEC manager server. I have explored many links and articles about it but everywhere they have mentioned entering the IP value through prompt using /var/ossec/bin/manage_agents. I was referring below link for setup: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-monitor-ossec-agents-using-an-ossec-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may provide the name and IP of the agent using the `-a` and `-n` modifiers.
For example to add an agent named "test-agent" without any restriction on IP simply run:

```
/var/ossec/bin/manage_agents -a any -n test-agent
```

You may then extract the key information with the `-e` modifier and import this into your agent. It will be necessary to restart the manager after adding the agent.

It's worth noting that Wazuh, which is a fork of OSSEC that heavily improved the original functionality over the last 5 years, includes a [self-registration service](https://documentation.wazuh.com/4.0/user-manual/registering/index.html) which can help you automate the process of agent registration and the installers can leverage this through the use of [deployment variables](https://documentation.wazuh.com/4.0/installation-guide/wazuh-agent/deployment_variables/deployment_variables.html).